# .htaccess rewrite on $page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

It seems I am stuck. I have found answers, but I can't get them to work.

I am working on [this website](http://mopra.dk/projects/outstander/). I use a switch to determine what content should be visible. I use the variable $page.

The links with this method are not good for SEO so I want them to be `/example` instead of `index.php?page=example`.

I have looked at all the different answers to this on StackOverflow, but I can't get any solutions to work. There are no errors coming up and the site will show just fine, but the rewrite doesn't work.

I have tried on both my servers on servage.net and one.com

Any suggestions? :D would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked? Please post some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`), then point your browser to `example.com/somepage`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ page=$1 [L,R]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.
This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`